# Which workflow should I use for this nested repo situation?

Tags: git, github

I am creating a git tutorial for beginners.

I'm tracking my progress such as notes, beamer slides and exercises in a git repo (repo A). I also want to create a sample git repository (repo B) with an educational commit history and ideally nest it inside repo A. I want to be able to push repo A to github including repo B.

I have found different approaches, such as submodules, subtrees and just putting repo B into repo A's .gitignore. What's the right choice in my situation?

Comment: I'm sorry, how is this question "opinion based"? I'm looking for an approach that actually, objectively works well in this situation and covers caveats I may not be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option A: Repo as instructions

I would recommend against trying to store the "educational git repo" as a repository at all.

As you intend to use it as an "sample git repository", I'd rather store it as a sequence of **bash commands** that are needed to recreate it, starting with  the initial `git init my-project && cd my-project`.

That way, using the basic git commands already can be trained while setting up the environment. File creation can be automated, `touch README.md` or `echo "int main() {}" > main.c`, and any beginner-reachable situation should be only a few commits away.

This format is also quite common in Q&A's on this platform; example answer: [Branch off master but include changes from another unmerged branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62018248/2375855)

### Option B: Simply do not nest

As it is an already advanced technique to nest repos, why not prepare the possibly complex training repo as an **indepdent**, publically accessible repo that is only one `git clone` away? That way, any setup reduces to a single command, and most exercises can be reset by one call to `git reset --hard origin/main` (although one might need to warn against this command's frequent use outside of training situations..)

### Option C: Training wheels repo webapp

There are dedicated webapps for learning more advanced branching, merging, rebasing scenarios without the "difficulty" of a real repository first. A popular one is https://learngitbranching.js.org/. In this application, you work against the visualization of the commit tree, and any real work in the working tree is simply simulated by calling `git commit` to create an opaque change.

The focus is on the logical relationship between commits and history manipulation. That way, one can first train oneself to mentally visualize and manipulate commit structures *quickly*, before going into a real repository with its added complexity of file contents and merge conflicts.

Comment: Thank you, option A didn't come to mind. I'm leaning towards option B for now, since I want to to create repo B in any case to play around with it. I'll probably cover some intermediate topics such as merge conflicts and cherry-picks and wouldn't want to do all the file editing with `sed` or similar.

Comment: There's always `echo "Foo" >> A.txt` for append, and `echo "Bar" > A.txt` for replacement. But yes, if your files shall look like real documents, a prepared repo is the better option.

Comment: Although with  option B it feels a bit awkward to have the slides that explain/visualize repo B in repo A.

Comment: Why is that? Isn't repo B simply "supplementary material", just like any literature or text would be? Plus: new option C, which I found to be very helpful to communicate and train the mental model of the git commit graph [beyond repeating stock commands](https://xkcd.com/1597/)...